# How to fix 'Cannot read property 'joinColumns' of undefined' error in EntitySchema for one to one relation

Tags: graphql, typeorm

I have 2 collections ProductVariant and Inventory

```
module.exports = new EntitySchema({
    name: 'ProductVariant',
    target: ProductVariant,
    columns: {
        id: {
            primary: true,
            type: 'varchar',
        },
        image: {
            type: 'json',
            nullable: true,
        },
        productId: {
            type: 'varchar',
        },
    },
    relations: {
        product: {
            target: 'Product',
            type: 'many-to-one',
            joinColumn: {
                name: 'productId',
            },
        },
        inventory: {
            target: 'Inventory',
            type: 'one-to-one',
            inverseSide: 'variantId',
            cascade: true,
        },
    },
});
```

and inventory

```
const EntitySchema = require('typeorm').EntitySchema;
const Inventory = require('../models/inventory').Inventory;

module.exports = new EntitySchema({
    name: 'Inventory',
    target: Inventory,
    columns: {
        id: {
            type: 'varchar',
            primary: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        sku: {
            type: 'varchar',
            nullable: true,
        },
        variantId: {
            type: 'varchar',
        }
    },
    relations: {
        variant: {
            target: 'ProductVariant',
            type: 'one-to-one',
            cascade: true,
            joinColumn: {
                name: 'variantId',
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Now if I run this query

```
const products = await ProductRepo.find({ relations: ['collections', 'variants', 'variants.inventory'] });
```

I get an error saying `Cannot read property 'joinColumns' of undefined`

In my database, the relations are built out perfectly. The only thing that could be wrong here is that there is no path from variant to inventory but there's a path from inventory to variant. So it's not a 2-way thing. Just one to one from one side, but the ORM should have been smart enough to pick it right?
That's the only thing off here.

Can someone tell me how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

So the error here is simple. In inverse you don't mention the column name, you mention the relation. In my case if you see I have mentioned variantId, replacing it with variant, fixed it for me.